# SQL Server - Convert VarChar to Date in ALTER TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

Saw a few threads on this but I have a specific instance where I am trying to do the conversion within an ALTER TABLE statement.

```
ALTER TABLE Leads
ALTER COLUMN [Created Date] Date
```

This is throwing an error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Created Date is currently set as (varchar(max), null)

Comment: what do the values look like in that column.

Comment: MM/DD/YYYY  i.e, 10/24/2016

Comment: Does that column contains any blank space as value or any other string character?

Comment: Add a new column (date type), copy data, remove old column. Rename new column. (Look out for dependencies, views, indexes, stored procedures etc.)

Comment: @UnnikrishnanR no

Comment: can you implicitly cast it with a `SELECT CONVERT(DATE,[Created Date])` or does it also throw the same error?

Comment: @scsimon same error

Comment: @jarlh how do you suppose I copy the data?

Comment: So, apparently you have at least one row with invalid data. Find that one!

Comment: You must have a rouge value in there somewhere. Try `SELECT [Created Date] FROM Leads WHERE ISDATE([Created Date]) <> 1`

Comment: @scsimon A rouge value, you say? Not a vert, or jaune, or bleu?

Comment: @JohnHC rogue... a slight type-o, sheesh.

Comment: @scsimon is right as many others have also mentioned. i had a coquin value. embarrassing a bit, but thanks for helping me realize.

Comment: @scsimon Just playing, a tongue in cheek comment

Answer (score 10):

You could standardize the date format.  Something like this:

```
UPDATE Leads
    SET [Created Date] = TRY_CONVERT(Date, [Created Date], 101);
```

The third argument is for the MM/DD/YYYY format mentioned in a comment. This will convert the value to a date -- if it can -- and to `NULL` otherwise.  Then, SQL Server will use its default formats to convert back to a string.

NOTE:  If you do this, be sure you back up the table, so you don't lost the information in the column!

Then, your code should work:

```
ALTER TABLE Leads ALTER COLUMN [Created Date] Date;
```

You can find the rogue values by using:

```
select [Created Date]
from Leads
where try_convert(date, [Created Date], 101) is null and
      [Created Date] is not null;
```

Answer (score 2):

As per Jarlh:

```
ALTER TABLE Leads
ADD COLUMN CreatedDate Date;

UPDATE Leads
SET CreatedDate = cast(right([Created Date],4) + '-' + left([Created Date],2) + '-' + left(right([Created Date],7),2) as Date);

Alter TABLE Leads
DROP COLUMN [Created Date];

sp_rename 'Leads.CreatedDate', '[Created Date]', 'COLUMN';
```

Comment: This has some serious assumptions. What if the value is '1/1/2016'? What if the value has a leading space? Clearly the OP's column had errors... but even these examples would have converted with his code.

Comment: @scsimon True, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 0):

i think you must to create temp table 
and then insert all of records into temp table then
rename temp table and original table

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: 1-Create Temp Table  2-Insert and cast all records from original table into Temp Table 3-rename Temp table and orginal table

Comment: That makes sense, probably a safer approach, but it is not what the OP asked.