# Conversion failed when converting my column from string to date

Tags: sql-server, date, type-conversion

When I try to convert my Exportdatum column from string to date, I always get an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My code:

```
ALTER TABLE [BLA1]
ALTER COLUMN [Exportdatum] DATE
```

Currently my BLA1.Exportdatum column looks like this:

```
15.05.2016
24.08.2014
...
```

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39618276/7713372

Comment: Converting dates to `date`... that is a wise thing to do.

Comment: Why use a varchar column to store dates ? I often wonder what makes people do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dd.MM.yyyy` isn't an unambiguous format, so SQL Server can't convert it. You'll first need to update the values to an ISO format (we'll use `yyyyMMdd` here);

```
UPDATE dbo.BLA1
SET Exportdatum = CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(date,REPLACE(Exportdatum,'.','/'),103),112);
```

Then you can `ALTER` your table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[BLA1] ALTER COLUMN [Exportdatum] date;
```

This does *assume* that all your dates are the format `dd.MM.yyyy`; if they aren't you're in for a very different world of "hurt" I'm afraid. Especially with you have dates like `'06.07.08'`, as that could be interpreted as many different dates.

Comment: There is no 24th month, so your assumptions should be correct.

Comment: The problem we often find (as I'm sure you're well aware @TimBiegeleisen ) is that once someone starts letting  their users input dates as strings, they (the users) will just use what ever format that they feel like at that moment. Very rarely do I see a system that allows users to input dates as strings **and** that system enforces the entry format. As soon as you have a system that allows strings for dates, and doesn't have an enforced format, all meaning of that data is utterly lost. *Of course, a system that stores dates as a string, even an enforced format string, is still wrong.*

Comment: Thank you very much ! Yes, my dates are all in the format dd.MM.yyyy;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that SQL Server internally recognizes this date format.  But, we can try using `TRY_CONVERT` with a bit of string manipulation:

```
WITH BLA1 AS (
    SELECT '15.05.2016' AS Exportdatum UNION ALL
    SELECT '24.08.2014'
)

SELECT
    Exportdatum,
    TRY_CONVERT(datetime, RIGHT(Exportdatum, 4) +
                          SUBSTRING(Exportdatum, 4, 2) +
                          LEFT(Exportdatum, 2)) AS Exportdatum_out
FROM BLA1;
```

### Demo

The strategy here is to convert your text dates to `YYYYmmdd` format, and then use SQL Server's `TRY_CONVERT` to handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. `dd.mm.yyyy` is not default accepted format in SQL. So first need to convert your values into standard date format. Then you may alter your column to datetime type.

```
Create table tt ( val varchar(100) )

insert into tt ( val ) values ( '15.05.2016' )

update tt set val = (RIGHT(val, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(val, 4, 2) + '-' + LEFT(val, 2)) 

Alter table tt alter column val datetime
```